# Selenium ChromeDriver not going to url using default user data

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It opens in a new window with the default start menu and shows a notification that Chrome is being controlled by automated test software, but it does not go to the url.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

What I also tried:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

The exception it gives

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
> Command duration or timeout: 61.65 seconds

I am using the lastest ChromeDriver 2.30 and Selenium 3.4.0 versions

Comment: Is the version of your Google Chrome between 58 - 60 ?

Comment: @renato Yes, it is 59

Comment: [Selenium Docker image](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeChrome) is setting `Chrome 53` and `ChromeDriver 2.30`. Can you try version `53` to see if it helps?

Comment: Did you open the chrome://version in your Chrome to get the profile path ? Seems like the path used in `--user-data-dir` argument is incorrect.

Comment: @Renato It is the correct one. Chrome appends /Default to the profile path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. It worked when I copied the Default folder from the profile path and moved it somewhere else.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/Desktop/");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "CHROME_DRIVER_PATH");        
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--no-default-browser-check"));
HashMap<String, String> chromePreferences = new HashMap<String, String>();
chromePreferences.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", "false");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.prefs", chromePreferences);            

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("CHROME_BINARY_PATH");
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work if I add `options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to move the profile, you can use the below (change `%Profile%` to the profile you want to use):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=%Profile%")
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```